# Symfony 4 - My Date (TextType) don't want to be not required

Tags: symfony, required

I've in my symfony 4 project a form with a date (TextType) :

```
->add('dateFin', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Retour le", "La date de fin du congé", [
                'required' => false,
            ]))
```

In my twig, I apply a datepicker javascript to this field :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#absence_dateDebut, #absence_dateFin').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', startDate: new Date()
                //     datesDisabled: [
                // // TODO: Griser les dates auxquelles l'user a déjà posé des congés et qui sont validés

                //     ]
            });
        })
```

So, it should be not required.
But When I submit my form, I've this :

[image]

My entity field :

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateFin;
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Have you a validation https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation ?

Comment: I think your problem is not required parameter, message is `This value is not valid`

Comment: I updated my first post, look my entity, I haven't any assert

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect your input, is it required ?

You have a strange "$this->getConfiguration" but I will assume this is normal.

I'm pretty sure you have a Assert() in your entity, don't you? (or any other entity validation)

Comment: No, in my entity I've : /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateFin;

Comment: What do you have in your $this->getConfiguration() ?

Comment: It's a function to set the label and placeholder from another class. But I resolved the problem with some Javascriptn thanks !